# how to visit a url using console command in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, console

I want to keep hitting an url for 100 times

So i wrote the below command in the console

```
for(i=1;i<100;i++)
{
this.document.location="http://URLLINK"
}
```

but this is not working since the document.location is changed
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you allow popups in the browser.

```
for(i=1;i<100;i++){
    window.open('http://URLLINK', '_blank');
}
```

Comment: this will create 100 pop ups :O ?

Comment: I took it from your description that you just want to hit the url 100 times so it wouldn't matter if you have to do so via opening multiple tabs. You can't achieve it on the same tab because you loose the javascript once the page is loaded.